# gdal 2.4 not reading tiffs as expected

Tags: python-3.x, gdal

I have two tiff files with 2 bands, both generated with the gdal 2.4 python binding.
Here they are
[image_ok](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IVvH4GrrqId6bRDZpvQU7yQJudmNTpQw)
[image_broken](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kzckZTvkIOTO7HbeB5GGgvoXcXuRvtcF)
They are supposed to be the same, according to gdal 2.4.
When I read them using gdal 2.2 or any tiff reading software, one of them seems corrupted, however gdal 2.4 does not see any difference between them.
Am I missing something ?

I tried multiple gdal version, it seems that since gdal 2.3 both tiff are being read the same

```py
import gdal
import numpy as np
file_ok = gdal.Open(r'./MOD10A1.A2019001.006.snow_multi.tif')
file_nok = gdal.Open(r'MOD10A1.A2019001.006.snow_multi_bd.tif')
band_ok = file_ok.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
band_nok = file_nok.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
print(np.array_equal(band_ok, band_nok))
print(gdal.VersionInfo("RELEASE_NAME"))
```

I expected gdal 2.4 to see the differences between the files, but they are being read as the same numpy matrix.
I also expected both gdal 2.2 and gdal 2.4 to have the same behavior.

Comment: Sorry about that, got the wrong links

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code prints `False` for me with GDAL 2.4.1 on Windows.

Comment: I just tried on windows and the code prints False. On ubuntu 16.04 it still prints True. Any ideas ?